# Open password protected MS Access database in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
.con_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & some_location & "\DB.accdb" _
& ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password='abc123';"
```

I am using VBA to open an access database which is password(abc123) protected, but i get an error that the password is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

it works with .mdb file extention. Thanks